# how to make a pull down menu which chnages background color

Tags: javascript, html, colors, background-color

i've tried to make a pulldown menu which changes the page background color, but it doesnt work.
any suggestions?

```
<body>

<select name="colors" onechange="changeColors(this)">
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="#868B8E">Grey</option>
    <option value="#FFC55C">Orange</option>
</select>

<script src="images8.js"></script>
</body>
```

the js

```
function changeColor(event)
{
    var color = event.value;
    document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0].style.backgroundColor=color;
    
}
```

Comment: Check the inline listener attribute of the select element, it's crowded with typos.

Comment: thanks guyss :) my gooffy ahhh has a little trouble sometimes 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code runs fine when the typos are corrected:

`onechange` -> `onchange`

`changeColors(this)` -> `changeColor(this)`

See working snippet

You might want to add an onload event to begin with the default colour.

```js
function changeColor(event)
{
    var color = event.value;
    document.getElementsByTagName('BODY')[0].style.backgroundColor=color;
    
}
```

```html
<select name="colors" onchange="changeColor(this)">
    <option value="blue">Blue</option>
    <option value="#868B8E">Grey</option>
    <option value="#FFC55C">Orange</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have few typos in your code:

Function call is "changeColors" but the function name is "changeColor".

Also the correct event name is "onchange" not "onechange"